# Move a NSButton from one point to another with CATransaction but after that i can't click on it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, catransition

I use below code for move a NSButton with animation from one point to another but after i do it i can't access button,means i can't click on it (it's disabled)

```
[CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
    btn.layer.frame=CGRectMake(200, 100, 48,48);
    [CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Can you click the area where the button has been before the transition?

Comment: i can't access all of areas on view after i move button

Comment: I tested this code with just a button in a window, and I can get the button's action to fire if I click in the area where the button was (the button itself just disappears).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that you're using CATransaction to do this move?  You can change the buttons frame with this one line, and everything works fine:

[btn.animator setFrame:NSMakeRect(200, 100, 48,48)];

(I don't have any experience with CATransaction, so I can't say why that's not working)

Comment: thank you,it works.but with this way we can't set speed for moving,is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can add the line:  [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:2];